# Display all products in Magento static block product_list

Tags: magento

I use this code on my CMS home page to display all the products from the root category:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" column_count="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

It works fine, but I would like to set the limit to "all", to show all products without pagination.

This doesn't seem to work:
http://mydons.com/how-to-show-products-with-toolbar-and-pagination-in-magento-static-block/

Is there any other way to do it in Magento 1.6.2? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a limit through xml/magic variables.

[Source: Setting columns and limiting products shown in grid](http://www.jimcode.org/2011/04/magento-setting-columns-limiting-products-shown-grid/)

Best option to show all of your products in this way would be to create your own module that fetches product collection, relying on Layer class

Comment: Ok. So there is no easier way of just displaying all products on the home page? Also, could you please elaborate on your "best option", and "relying on Layer class". Is that what the Jimcode page is talking about?

Comment: Well if you're using magento's class on your homepage it will only display default number of products (default is set up in your admin). You can create a new module that would extend Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer or one of the Block classes - you only need a snippet that fetches a collection and Layer's _prepareProductCollection class